# Web.config httpredirect is inserting a backslash when I don't want one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, web-config

I'm updating a site into a more dynamic version of the site.  And in the new site I use hash tags rather than a new page for every change in content.

I'm using web.config files in directories to redirect but it's adding a backslash.  Is there anyway to avoid this?  I'm already handling it in the redirect, but I feel it's kinda kludgy.

Here is an example web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/legal/#!terms-of-use" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Edit: It's worth mentioning, that instead of going to "/legal/#!terms-of-use" it goes to "/legal/#!terms-of-use/"  Note the backslash at the end.

Comment: That doesn't make a great deal of sense as a path, shouldn't it be "/legal#!terms-of-use"?

Comment: Not at all.  IIS would just redirect your suggestion to /legal/#!terms-of-use. as the path is actually /legal/default.aspx#!terms-of-use.  default.aspx is the default page for that folder so proper syntax of the path is with the backslash as "default.aspx" is handled by iis.

Comment: So, what if you change it to that (add default.aspx)?  Guessing that it's the default document path construction that is confusing the code.  By the way, have you looked in the location header and actually seen the trailing slash to make sure it's not being somehow added by the browser?

Comment: Would also try setting the exactDestination="true" attribute on the httpRedirect element

Comment: That's not considered best practices.  URL's are supposed to be easy to read and easy to index.  Adding default.aspx adds an unnecessary field to the URL that complicates SEO and is less pleasing to a client. As far as the second part of your question yes.  That url (and many like it) are linked in various places throughout the site.  It's being added as part of a redirect because httpredirect doesn't see a file extension.

Comment: exactDestination="true" worked, if you want to set that as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on exactDestination in your redirect element, as below:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/legal/#!terms-of-use" exactDestination="true" />
```